# CQ5 Sightly Accordion component

Tags: accordion, aem, sightly

Hi am trying to design an accordion component using sightly in AEM where instead of jsp we write html code along with different file for css and js under client libs.

I simply coded the below written part and wrote js for the same but am not able to see any changes ... Could someone please provide me a solution to implement the same.. ->when i click on show a parsys section opens up and when show converts to hide and when i click on hide the parsys section closes and hide converts to show.

```
<div data-sly-use.clientLib="${'/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html'}" data-sly-unwrap>
<css data-sly-call="${clientLib.css @ categories=['sd-singtel.accordion_2']}" data-sly-unwrap/>
<js data-sly-call="${clientLib.js @ categories=['sd-singtel.accordion_2']}" data-sly-unwrap/>
</div>  
<div data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}">Accordion_2 component</div>
<div class="about-contentcontainer">
<div class="about-content">
<div class="awards">
<h4> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="more">Show</span></a></h4>
<h4> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="more expanded">Hide</span></a></h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>// <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {

        alert("Hello");
        $(".awards h4 a").click(function() {

    enter code here
            $(this).parent().next().slideToggle("slow");
            var htmlStr = $(this).find(".more").html();
            if (htmlStr == "Show") {
                $(this).find(".more").html("Hide");
                $(this).find(".more").addClass("expanded");
            } else {
                $(this).find(".more").html("Show");
                $(this).find(".more").removeClass("expanded");
            }
        });
    });
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it, I think that this has little to do with Sightly or even with AEM. Also, I'm not sure which content you want to toggle.

Below's a working HTML fragment for toggling content (independent from AEM):

```
<style>
    .toggle-content {
        display: block;
    }
    .toggle-content-hide,
    .toggle-content-hidden .toggle-content-show {
        display: inline;
    }
    .toggle-content-show,
    .toggle-content-hidden .toggle-content-hide {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<a href="#" class="toggle-content">
    <span class="toggle-content-show">Show</span>
    <span class="toggle-content-hide">Hide</span>
</a>
<div>Sample content 1</div>

<a href="#" class="toggle-content">
    <span class="toggle-content-show">Show</span>
    <span class="toggle-content-hide">Hide</span>
</a>
<div>Sample content 2</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.toggle-content').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('toggle-content-hidden').next().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    })
});
</script>
```

To implement this in AEM, you should place the inline CSS into a CSS file of a client library, and the inline JS into a JS file of a client lib. I usually recommend to place them in the same client library within the component itself, so that everything that relates to that component is in the same folder. But when doing so, it is important to keep in mind that on a publish server, all /apps requests are forbidden by the dispatcher for security reasons, so all client libraries located under /apps should be merged and minified as one file that is typically located somewhere under /etc. To do so, you can use following repository node structure:

- `/apps/`

  - `mysite/`

    - `components/`

      - `mycomponent/`

        - `mycomponent.html` Sightly template
        - `clientlib/`
          `jcr:primaryType` = `cq:ClientLibraryFolder`
          `categories` = `[mysite.mycomponent]`

          - `css.txt` contains just a reference to style.css
          - `style.css` contains the style snippet
          - `js.txt` contains just a reference to script.css
          - `script.js` contains the script snippet
- `/etc/`

  - `designs/`

    - `mysite/`

      - `clientlib/`
        `jcr:primaryType` = `cq:ClientLibraryFolder`
        `categories` = `[mysite.publish]`
        `embed` = `[mysite.mycomponent, ...]`
        `dependencies` = `[mysite.jquery]`

The `embed` property of the /etc clientlib will make that it embeds and merges within the same file all clientlibs that are listed there. As opposed to the client libraries listed under the `dependencies` property, which will not get merged and will be served as a separate file. You can play with these properties to build the structure you need to optimize your site. There are also settings to automatically minify or not these files.

On the page, you then include the `mysite.publish` master clientlib located under `/etc`. So your page `<head>` element, would contain something like following Sightly template:

```
<head data-sly-use.clientLib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html">
    <sly data-sly-call="${clientLib.all @ categories='sd-singtel.accordion_2'}" data-sly-unwrap/>
</head>
```

If you're using AEM 6.1, you can even drop the `data-sly-unwrap`, because the `<sly>` tag has the same effect.

After that, the Sightly template of your component located under a path like `/apps/mysite/components/mycomponent/mycomponent.html` would look as follows:

```
<div data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}">mycomponent name</div>
<a href="#" class="toggle-content">
    <span class="toggle-content-show">Show</span>
    <span class="toggle-content-hide">Hide</span>
</a>
<div>${properties.myContentProperty}</div>
```